# $u=u(x,y), \frac{{\partial}^2u}{\partial x^2}=\frac{{\partial}^2u}{\partial y^2}\Rightarrow u''_{11}=u''_{22}$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

$u=u(x,y), \frac{{\partial}^2u}{\partial x^2}=\frac{{\partial}^2u}{\partial y^2}\Rightarrow u''_{11}=u''_{22}$?, where $u_{11}''$ is notation of second partial derivative with respect to the first variable, the same to $u_{22}''$

This question comes from the following problem.

If $$u'_1(x,2x)=x^2\;(1)$$ and $$u(x,2x)=x\;  (2)$$, u's second order partial derivative is continuous and  $\frac{{\partial}^2u}{\partial x^2}=\frac{{\partial}^2u}{\partial y^2}$,then what's $u''_{11}(x,2x)=$?

What the author did:

Take derivative of equation $(1)$ with respect to $x$, then take derivative of equation$(2)$ with respect to x(say, give us $(3)$), then take derivative of equation $(3)$ with respect to $x$.
And the author use the property$u''_{11}=u''_{22}$, which seems unreasonable to me when $y$ is a function of $x$.

Comment: Perhaps $u_{11}''$ is merely notation for: second partial derivative with respect to the first variable.

Comment: Notations are very confusing. What are $u_{11}$ and $u_{22}$?

Comment: @GEdgar It is, but when $y$ is a function of $x$,say $y=2x$, this equation still holds ?

Comment: @GEdgar If $y=2x$, then $\frac{{\partial}^2u}{\partial x^2}=\frac{{\partial}^2u}{\partial (2x)^2}$, which seems not correct.